# How can I get the ID/Name of the selected DocumentLibrary using JavaScript in MasterPage?

Tags: document-library, javascript, custom-masterpage

I want to get the ID/Name of the DocumentLibrary when I Click/Select on any library from List of libraries from the Left Panel of MasterPage.

Can I call the function from MasterPage or where ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned exactly in what context (server/client) however via ECMA Javascript is quite easy (somehow irrelevant if you are in the master page at the time of execution) -

```
var value = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(id);
```

See more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410971.aspx

I use a similar function on a Ribbon button. You might want to combine this call with ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded (see more here http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/11/01/using-the-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-part-1.aspx)

```
function getSelectedIds() {
                        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                        var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
                        var selectedItems = '';
                        for (index in items) {
                            selectedItems = selectedItems + ',' + items[index].id;
                        }
                        return selectedItems.substring(1, selectedItems.length);
                    }
```

Still, considering that actual request and the purpose of a master page, i still fail to see a situation when you would considering adding such a constraint (or need) into your master page. May I suggest you rather consider using Delegate controls (an example here http://howtosharepoint.blogspot.ch/2010/04/how-to-use-delegate-controls-in.html)